# import error in kivy ububtu but it work in windows

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote a .kivy file that works fine in Windows, but when I run it in Ubuntu, it gives me an error.

this line work fine in window.

```
#:import BottomNav libs.components.bottom_nav.BottomNav
```

but in ubuntu it raise this error:

```
unable to import package'libs.component.bottom_nav.BorromNav
```

i am using this code in HomePage:

```
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import BottomNav libs.components.bottom_nav.BottomNav

<HomePage>:
    md_bg_color: get_color_from_hex("#FFFFFF")
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        do_scroll_y: True

        # Appbar
        AppBar:
        # free section
        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True
            height: "25dp"
            padding: 10
            MDLabel:
                text: root.free_label
                halign: "center"
                valign: "center"
                font_size: 16
                font_name: 'assests/fonts/b.ttf'

        MDBoxLayout:
            ScrollView:
                bar_width: 0
                MDBoxLayout:
                    adaptive_height: True
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        adaptive_height: True
                        id: timeline
                        # FreeCourses
                        ScrollView:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height: 110
                            bar_width: 0

                            MDBoxLayout:
                                adaptive_width: True
                                spacing: 5
                                padding: 5

                                MDBoxLayout:
                                    adaptive_width: True
                                    padding: 5
                                    spacing: 5
                                    id: free_courses    
       
        # Bottom Navigation Bar
        BottomNav:
            avatar: root.profile_picture
```

and this is bottom_nav.kv:

```
<BottomNav>:
    adaptive_height: True
    spacing: 10
    padding:10

    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'home'
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'magnify'
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'movie'
    MDIconButton:
        icon: 'heart-outline'

    FitImage:
        source: root.avatar
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 25, 25
        radius: [25,]
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.